# Timestamp difference in numeric

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I want to get the difference between two timestamps in days with decimals.

i.e. instead of interval, `3 days 20:33:54.937`,
the desired output is `3.85` (in numeric format)

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--+
|        date1        |      date_2         |  |
+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| 2020-12-22 08:10:11 | 2020-12-18 11:36:16 |  |
+---------------------+---------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b8b4cbcb5c9a9aec62aa9e0e475f0b6)

You can use `EXTRACT(epoch FROM your_interval)` which returns the seconds of the interval. These can be converted into days:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(
    epoch FROM (
      '2020-12-22 08:10:11'::timestamp - '2020-12-18 11:36:16'::timestamp
    )
)/3600/24
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing is to get a number of seconds (with `epoch`) and then divide that into days

```
SELECT extract(epoch from (timestamptz '2021-01-12 13:55:23.631389+00' - timestamp '2021-01-09 09:55:23.631389+00')) / (24*60*60);
      ?column?      
--------------------
 3.1666666666666665
(1 row)
```